# Is it legal to sell Christmas themed products that taste of liqueur but have no clear/apparent indication of any alcoholic contents on the label?

Tags: england-and-wales, consumer-protection, alcohol, food, labelling

Waitrose and partners sell in their CHRISTMAS series of products an EXTRA THICK VANILLA CREAM which is described at the top of the back label as a

> “Sweetened blend of pasteurised extra thick double cream, double cream from Jersey breed cows with [LUXARDO] Vanilla and Vanilla seeds,”

and lists in its ingredients:

> Double cream (**milk**), jersey double cream (**milk**), sugar, Luxardo (R) Vanilla (5%), flavouring, exhausted vanilla seeds

The product package seems to make no mention in these two key information areas of any alcoholic content or percentage whatsoever, although Bob does wonder why vanilla ingredients may be so fancy that they have a trademarked brand. He notices at the bottom of the back label a note that

> LUXARDO is a registered trademark of Girolamo Luxardo S.p.A. Waitrose is an authorised user thereof.

Which confirms his interpretation without making any indication of alcoholic content.

But after buying a cup on clearance, and not needing any staff approval of appropriate age for alcoholic product purchase, Bob notices that the product tastes of rum, and begins posting on stack exchange to find out whether the legal situation would suggest if there is possibly any liquor in the product at all, before then re-examining the usually less-interesting parts of the labelling as he picks the package up to transcribe the ingredients list and product description. He notices an inconspicuous note in small but CAPITAL print at the bottom right of the front label that states

> CONTAINS ALCOHOL

Then he sees that the front centre product name in large print states EXTRA THICK VANILLA CREAM but has a very small printed note following it: “with LUXARDO Vanilla Liqueur”, though the more brightly coloured top of the package which Bob had read much more carefully before buying it simply read:

> WAITROSE & PARTNERS
> CHRISTMAS

> EXTRA THICK VANILLA CREAM
> Best before 8th Jan
> Keep Refrigerated

Nowhere does this product indicate an alcohol by volume percentage or anything similar. What is the legal status of this product and its packaging?

Comment: If you are asking what the significance of Bob’s interactions with the labelling are, it is to illustrate how one can be genuinely misled by the style of information presentation on the packaging.

Comment: I suspect that there is an alcohol regulation out there that specifies exactly what must be disclosed in what print under what circumstances. Also, the headline title question (no apparent disclosure on the label) is different from the body text question (inconspicuous disclosure on the label), in a way that is probably legally important.

Comment: Well, in my mind it isn’t contradictory because it truly wasn’t apparent at first glance. It was there, just (rather inconspicuous, so) not apparent in the way the product was displayed on the shelf.

Comment: do you know the word **flavouring**? Some extracts from alcoholic beverages are without alcohol and count os flavoring. At the other hand, small amounts of alcohol do not need to be disclosed with percentages.

Comment: @Trish why yes, as a matter of fact, I do know the word flavouring: I believe I have even used it in my question.

Answer (score 8):

### ABV labelling is only [required](https://www.premierlabels.uk.com/news/alcohol-labelling-requirements-explained) where it is above 1.2%

Presumably, the amount of liqueur used doesn’t bring the alcohol content to that level.

Answer (score 4):

[image: An image from waitrose.com, described below.]

From waitrose.com, here is an image (the best quality I could find online) of the 'front' of the container. To the right of "WAITROSE EXTRA THICK VANILLA CREAM" etc there is a column of data. The column is divided into two sections. In the second section, which indicates what is in each 30ml serving (about two tablespoons), there is a number I can't quite read. To the left of this reads "CONTAINS ALCOHOL" followed by one or two characters on the blue background.

> Is it legal to sell Christmas themed products that taste of liqueur but have no clear/apparent indication of any alcoholic contents on the label?

Regardless of the time of year, [drinks with more than 1.2% alcohol by volume (ABV) must show a warning](https://www.gov.uk/food-labelling-and-packaging/food-labelling-what-you-must-show).

> The product package seems to make no mention in these two key information areas of any alcoholic content or percentage whatsoever

This particular package says "CONTAINS ALCOHOL".

> What is the legal status of this product and its packaging?

It seems legal.

The mandatory information is within the field of vision. I assume the mandatory information has been printed with an [x-height of 1.2 millimetres or more](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/food-labelling-giving-food-information-to-consumers). Certainly the "CONTAINS ALCOHOL" is as legible in this poor quality image as the "Vanilla Liqueur".

Comment: also note: "With [brand]Vanilla Liquor" should be a tipoff that there is alcohol.

Comment: The two letters seem to be RI (which I think may mean recommended intake, but am not sure). The white column of data is split into two boxes. The top: “Per 100ml; Energy; 1833kJ; 444kcal;” The bottom: Per 30ml serving; Energy; 550kJ; 133kcal; 7%”. It seems to me that 7% is likely of the recommended caloric intake for an average and a reference to the white column to the right.

Comment: Thanks. RI does mean recommended Intake for average adult and 7% seems to be a reasonable value for the calories.

Comment: Unfortunately the entire question was originally very much based on the top label of the package which makes no mention or indication whatsoever of alcoholic content and may very well have a significant impact on the correctness of this answer.

Comment: Consider for contrast this or the similar “brandy pouring cream“ product that both indicate the alcoholic nature in the product name and so presumably also in the top of the package: https://supermarketwizard.com/waitrose/waitrose-christmas-clementine-cointreau-cream-053548-26805-26806

Comment: https://supermarketwizard.com/waitrose/waitrose-christmas-pourable-brandy-cream-869425-550431-550432

Comment: 1. The first time the phrase "top label" has appeared on this page is in your comment, so I don't know how the question "was originally very much based on the top label". 2. "alcoholic nature in the product name" - liqueurs tend to be alcoholic. But "brandy" or "liqueur" may not be sufficient. 3. Will edit answer to account for better info I've found.